# How do I read this sum? $\sum_{j \in N \setminus \{i\}} (x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) = 1$

Tags: summation

Let  $N = \{1,2,3,4\}, T=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and let $i,j \in N$.

I am trying to understand what the following sum means but am having a little difficulty in comprehending it:

$$\sum_{j \in N \setminus \{i\}} (x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) = 1 \qquad \forall i \in N, t \in T$$

Would someone be able to give me an example of what a few iterations of this would look like? I am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Edit: To help clarify the context, this is supposed to read as:
$x_{i,j,t}$ is a game between team $i$ and $j$ at time $t$, at team $i$'s home stadium.

The sum is supposed to read as: "Each team $i$ plays exactly once per period $t$."

Comment: $N\setminus \{i\}$ `N\setminus \{i\}`

Comment: This is a constraint for each $i \in N$ and $t \in T$. You should try picking two specific values and see if you can rewrite the constraint. For example, if $i=1$ and $t=1$, what would $N\setminus \{1\}$ equal? And what would the equation be?

Comment: For team i, the sum is over all other teams (N is the set of teams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, when $i = 4$ and $t = 2$, then $N\setminus\{i\} = \{1,2,3\}$.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j\in\{1,2,3\}}(x_{4,j,2} + x_{j,4,2}) &= 1\\
\text{or}\\
(x_{4,1,2} + x_{1,4,2})&\\
+(x_{4,2,2} + x_{2,4,2})&\\
+(x_{4,3,2} + x_{3,4,2}) &= 1\\
\end{align*}$$